# What wrong with my cout?

Tags: c++, linux, cout

In C++, Ubunt 12.04, I have a file named `config.txt` which contains `user name` and `password`. I have 2 `public static string` variables:  `USER` and `PASSWORD`. This is my code:

```
// Read file from config
string text[2];
int count = 0;
while(!fin.eof()){
    getline(fin,text[count]);
    count++;
    if(count == 2){
        break;
    }
}
CONNECTOR::USER = text[0];
CONNECTOR::PASSWORD = text[1];

string userAndPassword =  CONNECTOR::USER + ":" + CONNECTOR::PASSWORD;
cout << CONNECTOR::USER << endl; // It's fine, right user: qsleader
cout << CONNECTOR::PASSWORD << endl; // ok, right password: 123456
cout <<"user and password: " <<  userAndPassword << endl; // It's weird text! Problem here!
```

The weird text result is: `:123456d password: qsleader`!! This is not what I expected! But I don't know why this happen? Can anyone give me an suggestion? (If i print: `cout << "user and password: qsleader:123456"`,  the result is good!!)!

Comment: Are you sure it's just a copy error?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: Sure! Because I must try to hide my real `class CONNECTOR`!

Comment: Maybe your file contains leading whitespaces with the value `0x08`, which maps to backspace, and therefore kills part of your output

Comment: No, I checked it! No whitespaces! :(!

Comment: Is this exactly the code you are compiling and running? Because this should work then. If you altered the code for posting it here, then chances are high, that the defect part is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is created when you read the values. Indeed, I guess that your file has the two items on two different lines. Furthermore, I guess this file uses Windows line endings. Therefore, when you read the first item, it reads `qsleader\r` and then stops as the next extracted character is `\n`, extracted but not appended to the string.

When you create the `userAndPassword` string, it is in fact `qsleader\r:123456`. This special character `\r` is a return carriage. It makes the cursor go to the beginning of the line. Therefore, on the last line, you first output `user and password: qsleader`, then go back to the first column, and write `:123456`, resulting in `:123456d password: qsleader`.

Comment: Excellent answer...haven't thought of windows line endings

Comment: @Chris File name is `config.txt`. The extension is a clue.

Comment: Nice work! How I can express my great thank to you!! Thanks you very much! I port my work from `windows` to `Ubuntu` and this the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `userAndPassword` to a hellish expression involving assignments. I guess your intent was:

```
string userAndPassword = CONNECTOR::USER + ":" + CONNECTOR::PASSWORD
```